# Ruby on Rails 5 - find instances without an association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I want to Find Products which are not in Orders. How do I find them?

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord
   belongs_to :user
   belongs_to :address
   has_many :line_items, dependent: :destroy
   has_many :products, through: :line_items
end

class Product < ApplicationRecord
  validates_presence_of :name
  has_many :line_items
  has_many :orders, through: :line_items 
end

class LineItem < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :order
  belongs_to :product
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following query. i think it should help you.

```
Product.includes(:line_items).where(line_items: { id: nil })
```

or

```
Product.includes(:line_items).where(line_items: {product_id: nil})
```

Answer (score 4):

```
Product.left_outer_joins(:line_items).where(line_items: { id: nil })
```

This will return products with no associated rows in the `line_items` table - which in practice means that they have no associated orders.

This should be more performant than a SELECT DISTINCT query as you don't need to fetch a bunch of ids just to use in the negation.

Comment: I guess you mean `includes` instead of `joins` :)

Comment: @AlexTatarnikov `left_outer_joins` is actually preferable in Rails 5.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following query as you have used many to many relationship between product and order

```
Product.where('id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT(product_id FROM line_items))')
```

I hope this will work for you.